# Updating apps with Developer Portal doesn't update the application

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm currently working on my first Teams App which means modifying the manifest.json through the Microsoft Teams Developer Portal.  Whenever I make changes and try to update the application through "Preview in Teams" or "Publish to org" it doesn't update to the most recent version.

When I modify the app configurations and version and try to update or publish the application. The changes aren't reflected.  When I go to "Apps" in the sidebar and click on my app that is installed and look at the version, only the old version is shown.

Is there a way to make sure MS Teams pulls the most recent version?  I tried even quitting teams and opening it again. I have also tried downloading the package and installing it from the package.  Still the same version.

Comment: Can you please share some repro steps and screenshots, so that we can check on it from our end?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement and share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end?

Comment: We are unable to repro the scenario. It's working fine for us. have you tried to change the manifest version?when tried it first time it will 1.0.0 but when we change it will show the change version.[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeQUg.png

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Yes. I make changes in the Developer Portal to the app.  Like adding an app feature.  Then I change the version number.  I see that the version number changes.![](https://i.imgur.com/RSdKqoT.jpg)

Comment: Then i go to public to org section and click "Submit app to update.  After doing so, the version doesn't change. ![](https://i.imgur.com/6SG7Yl9.jpg).  I have also tried publish to org ![](https://i.imgur.com/eS30Lw7.jpg).  No difference in Version

Comment: Also, when I go to the Apps section, the version does not change ![](https://i.imgur.com/aRHXZ40.jpg)

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT, how do I change the manifest version in the Developer Portal?  I only see a way to change the version in the "Basic information" section.  It does appear that there is a version and a manifest version. I'm not seeing how to modify the manifest version ![](https://i.imgur.com/OXGmRpP.jpg)

Comment: It appears the only way I can get it to update is through uploading the package in the Teams Admin Center.  Then I have to restart Teams and reinstall the app. ![](https://i.imgur.com/FZHEcyJ.jpg)

Comment: You can change the version in developer portal. If you want to change the manifest version , you need to download the app package then you can change it manually.
https://youtu.be/q8XG_TuNwvU

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT. Sorry, the video doesn't work for me.  I can change the version in the developer portal but it doesn't change what is installed for Teams.  I have tried updating but it doesn't work as well.  Am I missing a step?

Comment: Could you please check it once now it is visible or not?
https://youtu.be/uM-W0ZJehG4

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT.  The video is private.  Can you allow me access so that I can review it?

Comment: https://youtu.be/XZRFPXg0AL4 added as public.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that and it doesn't refresh.  I've been able to update the app in the teams admin portal.  It takes a little bit for the changes to reflect in the teams client.

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved or still looking for any help?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I have found a workaround. Thank you.

Comment: @vangj can you please post what worked for you? I am going through the exact same issu.